# Find expressions in simplest form for the perimeter and area

Tags: geometry

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Ju9.png)

Sorry for lack of detail but i am not sure how to proceed with this one. i have tried my hardest but cannot seem to work it out. could anyone show me the steps to work it out and the answer i would really appreciate it and would be really grateful

thanks

Comment: I'd say information insufficient for the first one, it doesn't *have* to be a circular quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

1) $$S=x(x+1)+ \frac{\pi x^{2}}{4}$$
$$P = 2(x+(x+1))+\frac{\pi x}{2} $$
2) $$S=x(3x-3)- \frac{\pi x^{2}}{4}$$
$$P=x+2x-3+3x-3+\frac{\pi x}{2}$$
3) $$S=x^{2}+ 2\pi x^{2}$$
$$P= 4\pi x$$

Answer (score 0):

To get you started.

$b$ that is the hardest one.

The area of a circle is $\pi r^2$.

You have a rectangle with a circle sector removed.

The circle sector is a quarter of

a circle and has radius $x$, i.e. its area is $\pi x^2 /4$

The sides of the rectangle are

$2x - 3 + x$ and $x$.

Its area is $(2x - 3 + x) \cdot x = 3x^2 -3x$

Now we have to subtract the circle sector

$A = 3x^2 -3x - \pi x^2 /4$

$A = x^2(3 - \pi/4) -3x$